# How do we export blender material with shaders and blender texture to unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, blender, materials, export

I've blender model, it has noise texture and glossy shaders, when I import it to unity, they are not the same.
I tried both cycle and Eevee render and was looking for different ways to export the fbx file, but nothing seems to work.

I am not sure, if it is even possible to export to shaders and noise texture from blender to unity or do I have to create material from scratch in unity?

This seems to be very common problem while importing material from blender to unity.
I am able to find way to get UV color mapped material, I did it by creating new material in unity and add same texture image file that I used in blender.

Her is the my material in blender.
[image: here is the material setting in blender]

I tried using copy path option while exporting, but no luck

[image: export setting in blender]

When I imported the file in blender,I've extracted the material like this

[image]

After extracting a .mat file appeared, but it doesn't have information related to noise texture or any blender shaders.
this is the only file I can see after extracting the material.
[image]

Comment: Blender and Unity use different renderers, so in general you will not get a direct conversion from one to the other that looks the same.